# I need to convert a date in String format to an actual date in order to check if it's Friday

Tags: java, date, datetime

I have a date in String format, in the following manner "2016-07-08" (8th July 2016). I need to check if this is a Friday, the reason is that the date will change and I will always need to check if the provided date is Friday. I am using the following code (assume startDate is a String which holds my date):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd"); 
java.util.Date date = formatter.parse(startDate); 
cal.setTime(date); 
if(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.FRIDAY){  
  System.out.println("IT'S FRIDAY!!!!");    
}
```

I tried outputting the value that is stored in cal, and it is returning Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 CET 2016.

Answer (score 3):

Capital `Y` is for week-year. You probably meant `yyyy-MM-dd` (with lower case `y` for the year).

The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) lists all the valid patterns.

Answer (score 2):

It should be `yyyy`, not `YYYY`.

Use this.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in pattern used for parsing years. Instead of creating SimpleDateFormat with `YYYY-MM-dd` please use this instead

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `"yyyy-MM-dd"` as the date format with lower case 'y'.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct. But the Question and Answers use outmoded classes.

## java.time

The java.time framework supplants the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java.

```
Boolean isFriday = LocalDate.parse( "2016-07-08" ).getDayOfWeek().equals( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY );
```

The `LocalDate` class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The `DayOfWeek` enum has seven instances to represent and test the day-of-week.

You input string is in ISO 8601 format. The java.time classes use Those standard formats by default in parsing and generating String representations. So no need to define a formatting pattern.